# Access is denied when trying to connect the machine remotely using Powershell command

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am looking for the powershell script/command to connect the remote machine and execute the command further in that session.

Gone through various blogs and similar posts on Stackoverflow too and found that  we need to start the PS-Session to connect the remote machine. but No success for the solution.So, thought to raise a new question with the scenarios that I tried.

For that I have Enabled PSRemoting in both machines and also added the remote machine IPAddress and machine name in the trusted Hosts list. Still getting the Access is Denied error when executing the below commands.

```
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName [Machinename] -Credential username
```

Then I found that domain name is different in both machine. But for that if we add the machine name in trusted hosts, clear the Cache and reset the psconfiguration it should work.

But, Its still not working throwing the same error

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server [MachineName] failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\PathOfPowerScript\servertest.ps1:11 char:7
       Enter-PSSession –ComputerName [MachineName] -EnableNetworkAccess -C ...
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ([MachineName]:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Anyone with working solution or suggestions to move ahead.

Comment: As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) state: _Credential: Type a user name, such as User01 or Domain01\User01, or enter a PSCredential object generated by the Get-Credential cmdlet. If you type a user name, you're prompted to enter the password._. So use a real [PSCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) object for `username`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the steps mentioned in the question, the additional setting done was
"winrm quickconfig" at the remote computer which was required to be connected.

Then executing the

```
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName [MachineName] -EnableNetworkAccess -Credential [username] -Authentication Default
```

the session gets started and then I was able to execute and get details of the remote machine regardless of same or different domain